# Связь в бессоюзном предложении?

Tags: синтаксис

После поражения в войне индейцы практически полностью лишились земли: им были оставлены лишь небольшие плодородные территории, названные индейскими резервациями.

Связь между частями предложения: пояснение или причина?

Answer (score 1):

Поясняет, раскрывает смысл.После поражения в войне индейцы практически полностью лишились земли(как это произошло?можно подставить "а именно" ): им были оставлены лишь небольшие плодородные территории, названные индейскими резервациями

Вопрос почему? неуместен: они лишились земли не потому,что им оставлены...и т.д.